# 'The download has failed' while trying log in to VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I get following pop-up when trying to log in to VS2017:

[image]

I read online to try logging in through the installer which gives me this error:

"Error signing in: 'An exception has occurred of type: Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException.'"

Anyone know what I can do?

Comment: did you try doing a repair on visual studio?  Sound like something did not install right

Comment: Yes, also tried reinstalling, but I get the same error